# SharePoint - Word Automation convert word to pdf

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, word-automation

I have web application and I used SharePoint as my backend. In my web application the user can save word file in SharePoint folder.

I want to create a service that takes that 'word' file and convert it to PDF file.
I understand that I need to use 'Word Automation' service but I have no idea how.

There is any work flow that knows how to do that? Or I need to write code that does that?
And if I need to write a code, where do I write it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA: Within Excel how do I save a word document as a PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187516/vba-within-excel-how-do-i-save-a-word-document-as-a-pdf)

Comment: Access VBA can automate Word. No idea how to integrate with web application, if possible.

Comment: No sorry, but it is not what I'm looking for. SharePoint has service called "Word Automation".  I still dont understand how to use this service and convert "word" files into "pdf" files

Comment: Okay, what about this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71830255/sharepoint-word-automation-services - modify the PowerShell script to VBA.